# After clone Laravel project, I have 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on my project (I had that on the github). I clone this project and after I try open that (php artisan serv) I had an error 500. I tryed create a new project and it works correctly. I found that propably generate na new key

```
php artisan key:generate
```

But I have this error

```
file_get_contents(/home/michal/ogloszenia/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
     92|     {
     93|         file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
     94|             $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
     95|             'APP_KEY='.$key,
  >  96|             file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
     97|         ));
     98|     }
     99| 
    100|     /**

      +17 vendor frames 
  18  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: create .env file into your project's root directory. And try again.

Comment: Following on from @KaushikThakkar you can find a default version of the .env here https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example